# TCP Packet size

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, packet

Im trying to send a TCP packet from client to server, I want to be able to select the size of the packet. The problem Im facíng is that the packet size is not correct if I dont put a Sleep(45) (milliseconds). Im using Wireshark to see the size of the packets.

To make sure u guys are with me Im going to explain as clear as possible.

I have tried to do like this..

First I select the amount a data I want to send. For example say 1Mb or "1000000ish"bytes. I allocate an array with so much space.

To be able to send a specific packet size I have allocate a sendbuffer which contains the size of the packet I want (my case 64, 512, 1024 and 1514 bytes). I fill the sendbuffer with letters. Say I want to send with 64 as packet size.

```
for (int i = 0; i < packetSize; i++){ 
            sendbuf[i] = 'a';
        }
```

To know how many times I have to send a packet to reach 1Mb I done this math.
nrOfTimes = (dataSize / packetSize).

Then to send it with a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nrOfTimes; i++) {
            rc = send(sConnect, sendbuf, packetSize, 0); //rc and sConnect contains information where to send the data, if you wonder

            Sleep(45); // If i dont use this the packet size gets 1514. 
        }
```

If I use the sleep(45) its working but its takes years to finished and Im supposed to measure the time so its incorrect to do like this. if I go lower then Sleep(45) then my network card ignors the packets size and put it to 1514 size.

Is there anyone who has some clear ideas what to do? I can only assume it might have something to do with the network card buffer.

Comment: TCP provides you with a stream of bytes, not packets, so you cannot easily make 1 send() call result in 1 recv() call. Does it really matter whether the receiving side receives a bunch of data from several of your send() calls ?

Comment: TCP is a STREAM. So you cannot send a specific size. You just keep sending your data until it's all there.

Comment: @nos Thats correct, my bad. My task is to be able to select the size of the packets. But I dont know who to make that....

Comment: If you want to send packets, you need a packet-oriented protocol, not TCP.

Comment: @molbdnilo The thing is that my task is to send packets with TCP and UDP. I can select the packet size for UDP, cause UDP its diffrent, Send and pray^^

Comment: @PetrusLindblom Then you have been given an impossible task. You need to talk to the task-giver and see if there's been a misunderstanding.

Comment: @PetrusLindblom The standard socket API doesn't give you any means to do that. You'd need to create your own implementation of TCP where you could control such things.

Comment: @molbdnilo That might be the case I guess, Im very confused about this task. Thank you!

Comment: @nos Yeah, I dont think Im supposed to do that either. Thank you anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a byte streaming protocol so it is incorrect to think of transmission in terms of discrete packets of bytes. It is likely you are interacting with the [Nagle algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) by injecting the 45 ms delays.

Comment: In wireshark the length is actually 106, so my 64 + header. But its correct lenth to see according to my Lector at the Uni.